# SQL count returning wrong values

Tags: sql

Was asked the question in regards to a olympic database.

"For each competitor who was in more than one event, list their given-name, family-name, their number of events, and their best and worst places (and no other data). 
List this information in in descending order of their number of events (i.e. most events first), 
and (when competitors have the same number of events) then in ascending order of best place, 
and (when the same best place) then in ascending order of worst place, 
and (when the same worst place) then in ascending order of their family-name."

I have been trying to write the query to do this, however it does not return the correct count. It stops at a count of 2 and does not return the correct min or max values.
The Tables are:

Competitors Table

```
Competitornum | Givenname | Familyname | Gender | Dateofbirth | CountryCode |
```

Results Table has

```
Eventid | Competitornum | Place | Lane | Elapsedtime | Note |
```

Query

```
SELECT c.Givenname, Familyname, COUNT(r.Competitornum), MIN(r.Place), MAX(r.Place)
FROM Competitors c
JOIN Results r 
ON c.Competitornum=r.Competitornum
Group by c.Givenname, familyname, place
Having Count(r.Competitornum) > 1
```

This is the query I have come up with so far and am not sure what I have wrong.

Comment: Which database is this? Oracle? Sybase?

Comment: The program is sqlfire. I'm unsure of the type sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to include `place` in your GROUP BY clause.

And you will need an ORDER BY clause to meet all the requirements.

```
SELECT c.GivenName, c.FamilyName, COUNT(r.CompetitorNum) events,
       MIN(r.Place) best_place, MAX(r.Place) worst_place
  FROM Competitors c
  JOIN Results r ON c.CompetitorNum = r.CompetitorNum
 GROUP BY c.GivenName, c.FamilyName
HAVING COUNT(r.Competitornum) > 1
 ORDER BY events DESC, best_place ASC, worst_place ASC, c.FamilyName ASC;
```

Comment: The only thing to watch for is that John Smith (number 123) and John Smith (number 234) could get conflated by the grouping.  It might be better to group by the competitor number too.  Except in MySQL (and maybe PostgreSQL), you would need to list the non-aggregate columns in the GROUP BY clause, so the names would still be listed there.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, having the competitornum in group by is a great idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, remove place from the GROUP BY

```
Group by c.Givenname, familyname
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the place field from the group by clause and then try to run your query.